# In an SSRS Tablix, how can I include two or more columns in a column group?

Tags: reporting-services

I have sales data (net, gross and tax) by region and month. I would like region going down the page and month across with a column in each month for net, gross and tax. It would look something like this:

> ```
>       Jan               Feb                Mar
>       Net   Gross  Tax  Net   Gross  Tax   Net   Gross  Tax
> ```
>
> East
>
> North
>
> South
>
> West

I can easily get one data column for each month. I can even get the three columns for each month but I can not get an individual column heading for each of Net, Gross and Tax. The column heading that SSRS gives me is for the first field that I drop on that part of the form. What I want to see under the 'Jan' heading is:

> Net   Gross  Tax

but what I get is:

> Net

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the query you are using, or at least the columns in your dataset? It isn't clear whether your dataset has separate columns for Net, Gross and Tax, or whether you have a single numeric value column, together with a row type of Net, Gross or Tax.

Comment: @Mark-Bannister The query is simple: SELECT Region, Month, Net, Gross, Tax FROM TotalPayments  ORDER BY Region, Month  The data has been summed and otherwise massaged earlier. Thanks for considering this.